# How to call a asyncTask several times inside a loop- one after another

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Actually what i am trying to do is that call an asyncTask several times inside a loop. So, first time the asyncTask will start immediately and from second time onwards, it will check whether the `AsyncTask` has been finished-if finished than again call it with different values.

Below is my code for the activity:

**In onCreate()**

```
btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
 {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
       {
        count_response = 0;
        newUploadWithSeparate();
      }
 });
```

**The newUploadWithSeparate() method:**

```
private void newUploadWithSeparate()
        {
            responseString_concat = "";

            if(filePath.length > 0)
            {
                for(int i=0;i<filePath.length;i++)
                {
                    count_response = i;

                    if(i == 0)
                    {
                        uploadAsync.execute(filePath[0]);

                        mHandler = new Handler() { 
                            @Override public void handleMessage(Message msg) { 
                                String s=(String)msg.obj;

                                  Log.d("logIMEI","\n Response from Asynctask:  " + s);

                                str_response_fromAsync = s;

                            }
                        };
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        uploadAsync.getStatus();

                        while(uploadAsync.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING) // this while loop is just to keep the loop  value waitining for finishing the asyncTask
                        {
                            int rx = 0; 
                        }

                        if(uploadAsync.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING)
                        {
                            if(uploadAsync.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED)
                                {
                                    if(str_response_fromAsync != "" || !str_response_fromAsync.equals("") || !str_response_fromAsync.isEmpty())
                                       {
                                        uploadAsync.execute(filePath[i]);

                                        x = i;

                                        mHandler = new Handler() { 
                                            @Override public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
                                            { 
                                                String s=(String)msg.obj;

                                                  Log.d("logIMEI","\n Response from Asynctask_" + x + ": "  + s);

                                                str_response_fromAsync = s;

                                            }
                                        };


                                       }
                                }
                        }
                    }

                 }
            }
        }
```

**And the asyncTask:**

```
private class UploadFileToServer extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> 
        {
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() 
            {
                super.onPreExecute();
            }


            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
            {
                return uploadFile(params[0]);
            }

            private String uploadFile(String pr)
            {
                //inside here calling webservice and getting a response string as result.        
                    MyWebsrvcClass mycls = new MyWebsrvcClass();
                    return responseString_concat = mycls.Call(xxx,yyy) ;
            } 

            @Override        
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
            {
                Log.d("logIMEI" , "\n count_response : "+ count_response + "  fileprath_len : " + filePath.length);

                    Message msg=new Message();
                    msg.obj=result.toString();
                    mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

                super.onPostExecute(result);  
            } 
        }
```

Now the problem is that its not working as expected. The first time when value of `i` is equals `0` than the `AsyncTask` gets called and after that its not getting called anymore.

Plus, when first time `AsyncTask` is called- its still not directly entering to `onPostExecute()`. When the loop ends totally and `newUploadWithSeparate()` method ends then the `onPostExecute()` is working.

Any solutions for this or any other way to do this job done for using `AsyncTask` inside loop?

Comment: You could put everything into the doInBackground method, use publishProgress() to return the server result and then just sleep the thread. Or use a service. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: You are using the same asynctask instance, and calling 'execute' on it multiple times. You should create a new instance of the asynctask in every iteration.

Comment: you can pass `array` of `params` and let the `task` handle them, publish the updates using `publishProgress`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call execute() on the same object more than once. So create a new instance of UploadFileToServer for each iteration of the loop.